# Como hacer que ngFor espere a que termine una funcion - Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic

estoy haciendo que al hacer tap en un Select llame a una funcion que a través de http se completa un Array con los valores que luego recorrerá el *ngFor , el problema es que al presionar el Select la primera vez no lo alcanza a cargar los valores, pero en la segunda vez que presiona ya carga el listado correctamente, supongo que es porque el array que recorrerá el ngFor aún no se rellena, por eso quisiera hacer que el ngFor espere a que la funcion opciones() haya terminado, como puedo hacerlo?

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="item.idTipo=='7'" on-tap="opciones(item.idPregunta)">
        <ion-item class="respuesta">
                <ion-select [(ngModel)]="select" okText="Seleccionar" cancelText="Cancelar">
                    <ion-option *ngFor="let opcion of Opciones[item.idPregunta]" [value]="opcion.nombreOpcion">{{opcion.nombreOpcion}}</ion-option>
                </ion-select>     
        </ion-item>                               
 </div>
```

TS:

```
opciones(reciboidPregunta){
    //recibo el id de la pregunta para cargar las opciones asociadas
    this.opcionPost.idPregunta=reciboidPregunta;

    this.authServiceProvider.postData(this.opcionPost, 'Opciones')
    .then((result) => {
      this.responseOpcion = result;
      //array que guarda como index a el id de la pregunta
      this.Opciones[reciboidPregunta]=this.responseOpcion.opciones;

      console.log(this.Opciones);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo intentaría que la consulta que se lanza cuando haces "tap" se haga antes, creo que no sería bueno para la experiencia de usuario dar "tap" y tener que esperar X tiempo hasta que "vengan" los datos del select, es posible, que se impaciente y haga "tap" varias veces seguidas.

Intenta cargar esos datos antes de que se haga 'tap'

Comment: El problema es que tengo todo este div dentro de otro *ngFor en el cual se cargan distintas preguntas y solo en las que el item.idTipo=='7' cargan estos Array con el idPregunta del mismo, por lo que no encuentro la manera de saber ese idPregunta antes como para cargarlo..